# Finding alternative for Metal bolted joint in Plastic part

Tags: design, mechanisms, plastic

I am developing a design for HDR Brachytherpy interstitial Template that has to be completely in plastics. There is a shaft of 25 mm and length 130 mm, which is held by a plate of 10 mm thickness and the plate is butted to a surface. My need is to arrest the sliding motion and rotation of the shaft once placed in the plate hole. Such that we can lock the shaft at any length.

Similarly it has multiple needles going through the shaft and plate which are needed to be locked at the plate such that e can arrest sliding motion of needles also.

In earlier design, there is a bolt and key that hold the shaft in its place. I need an alternative for locking the shaft at its position without using screws.

Comment: a cam lock or over centre clamp.

Comment: Ty for suggestion.